# Internal links denied access while direct access works w/ the browser URL

Tags: amazon-s3, jekyll, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static website that is housed in a S3 bucket. I am using CloudFront to keep the site under https. The viewer can see the home page under https (redirected from http) with no worries. However, when the user clicks off the home page onto a subordinate page (docs or blog) I get a access denied message. When I go directly to the page from the browser's URL address, I am able to see the page without error. I have enabled the bucket policy to include access to any page from http: "naked domain" and http://www."mydomain". I have also enabled CORS too.

I am baffled as to why the links are not working. I would appreciate any suggestions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between clicking a link or typing the URL directly. This suggests that there's something wrong with how the links are generating... Maybe you have a typo there?

Comment: I don't think you are going to the *exact* same link as is found in the HTML.   The XML error output suggests that you selected the bucket from the drop-down list when selecting an Origin Domain Name in CloudFront.  Instead, you need to paste the bucket's web site hosting endpoint hostname, as found in the S3 console.

Comment: With no url and no code, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: First, thank you all for your feedback.  Your comments had me diving into my code and ensure all URLs were correct.  I did discover the feed.xml file had the incorrect URL.  I corrected this and uploaded back to S3 and invalidated the existing code in the edge locations.  I did check the URL and learned that while I was able to drill down to the index.html file, yet the link only drilled down to the "home" directory for documents.   I added my _config.yml

Comment: The problem as I see it is the URL as @CaioProiete  and Michael - sqlbot eluded to in their commends.  The URL generated by Jekyll goes down to the directory level while I can add in the index.html file and it works.  I updated the environmental variable to reflect JEKYLL_ENV="production" and that corrected the host issue for me.  I am still getting the access denied error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference between clicking a link or typing the URL directly. This suggests that there's something wrong with how the links are being generated...

Maybe you have a typo there?